# is there any class method defined that can delete an object

Tags: python, class, methods

i am begineer in python and i am creating a employee managment system in which class employer  should have a method to delete a object but it seems impossible in python. i have tried many ways to do that but none of them worked for me. the only way it worked when i used del obj_name outside a class body which i clearly dont want

```python
class Employee:
    bonus = 1000
     
    def __init__(self,name ,salary,lang,post):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.salary = int(salary)
        self.lang = str(lang)
        self.post = str(post)
        
    
    def deleteAttr(self,attr):
        delattr(self, attr)
                
    def getInfo(self):
        print(f"Name of the person is {self.name}")
        print(f"Language of the person is {self.lang}")
        print(f"Post of the person is {self.post}")
        
    def getSalary(self):
        print(f"The salary for {self.name} is  {self.salary} ")   
     
    def inc(self,inc):
        self.salary = int(inc) +  self.salary
        print(f"Incremented salary is {self.salary}")
    
    def dec(self,dec):
        self.salary = self.salary - int(dec) 
        print(f"Decremented salary is {self.salary}")
        
class Employer(Employee):
    @staticmethod
    def fired(a):
        atr = a.__dict__
        for i in list(atr):
            delattr(a, i)
            del a
    def recruit(self,s,name, salary, lang, post):
        s = Employee(name, salary, lang, post)
                
    def __init__(self,name,salary,lang,post):
        super().__init__(name,salary,lang,post)
    
    def setBonus(self,incr):
        self.__class__.bonus += incr
        print(f"Bonus increased to {self.__class__.bonus}")
    
    def incBonus(self):
        self.bonussalary = self.salary + self.bonus
```

in this fired is the method i am trying to define where a is the object that i am willing to delete. i read somewhere that deleting all the attributes of an object can help in deleting it but even that is not working.please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Deletion of an object is not an operation on the object itself, it's an operation on the list or other container that refers to the object.

Comment: Delete the employee from what? Memory? That's a language implementation detail, not something your code should model. The instance of `Employer` should be removing an instance of `Employee` from an explicit container like a list.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you think "deleting an object" even means? If you have, say, an ``e: Employee = ...`` and you "delete" ``e`` – what would then be the result of ``print(e)``, for example?

Comment: Have you searched for it? What did you find?

Comment: deleting an object means that interpreter should give an name error that the name is not defined.so sorry i am not being clear

Comment: "deleting an object means that interpreter should give an name error that the name is not defined." – That's deleting a name, not an object – it's what ``del`` already does.

Comment: thank you so much for your help  i got it and sorry for bothering you all for this simplething

Answer (score 3):

This *screams* of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), so I'm not going to answer the question asked, and instead make notes on your design:

1. There is *no* reason for an `Employer` to be a subclass of `Employee`. Subclass relationships should follow an "is-a" relationship; unless an employer *is* an employee, it makes no sense to model the relationship that way (`Dog` can subclass `Animal` because a dog *is* an animal, but this doesn't apply to your scenario).
2. Deleting objects is easy. Just let the last name referring to the object go out of scope, directly or indirectly (or `del` it if you must), and the object goes away.

But you don't want to delete it, you want them to be fired and removed from the collection of employees from that employer. So don't model employers as employees, make them their own class that *contains* employees. And don't make `fired` a static method; that implies an employee is fired by all possible employers at once, not fired by a particular employer.

A reasonable model for `Employer` might be:

```
class Employer:
    def __init__(self, bonus=1000):
        self.employees = []
        self.bonus = bonus  # bonus argument and attribute only used if bonus is same for all employees of this employer, see below

    def recruit(self, name, salary, lang, post):  # Remove s, assignment won't work
        self.employees.append(Employee(name, salary, lang, post))
        return self.employees[-1]  # Give caller reference to new employee if they need it

    def fire(self, employee):
        self.employees.remove(employee)  # Will raise exception if employee doesn't work for this employer

    def setBonus(self, employee, incr):  # If this applies to one employee at a time
        employee.bonus += incr
        print(f"Bonus increased to {employee.bonus}")

    def setBonus(self, incr):  # If this applies to all employees for this employer
        self.bonus += incr
        print(f"Bonus increased to {self.bonus}")
    
    def incBonus(self, employee):
        # Little unclear what this was supposed to do; bonussalary wasn't an attribute for
        # anything except here in original code; I'll interpret it as returning the salary
        # inc(luding) bonus for the year for a given employee
        return employee.salary + self.bonus  # If bonus applies to all employees
        return employee.salary + employee.bonus  # If bonus applies per-employee
```

If you want to hide the `Employee` objects from the caller, you can have `self.employees` be a `dict` mapping a unique ID (e.g. generated via an `itertools.count` initialized in the constructor), and have `recruit` insert the new employee keyed by the unique ID, then return only the unique ID, and all other methods would accept that ID instead of the `Employee` object, look up the correct employee, and perform the work; this way, a given employee object is not directly exposed to the caller; when the employer fires them, they disappear. It's weird (people aren't *supposed* to live or die by their employment status), but you do you.

Just for completeness, a cleaned up `Employee` that matches the design for `Employer`, with the assumption that `bonus`es are company-wide (not per-employee):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, lang, post):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.salary = int(salary)
        self.lang = str(lang)
        self.post = str(post)
             
    def print_info(self):  # Not named get; get implies you *return* the info; use snake_case over camelCase per Python's PEP8 style guide
        print(f"Name of the person is {self.name}")
        print(f"Language of the person is {self.lang}")
        print(f"Post of the person is {self.post}")
        
    def print_salary(self): # See above for name change reason
        print(f"The salary for {self.name} is {self.salary}")
     
    def give_raise(self, amount_raised):  # Much more explanatory name than "inc"
        self.salary += int(amount_raised)  # Avoid repeating self.salary using +=
        print(f"Incremented salary is {self.salary}")  # Disagree with printing when this happens, but you do you I guess
    
    def cut_pay(self, amount_lost):  # Again, explanatory names are good (makes it clear value expected to be positive
        self.salary -= int(dec)   # Avoid repeating self.salary using -=
        print(f"Decremented salary is {self.salary}")
        # If not for the prints in each, I'd just implement this as:
        return self.give_raise(-amount_lost)
        # to reduce code duplication, or replace both functions with a single 
        # function, "adjust_salary" that takes a positive value for raises, 
        # negative for cuts, but leaving it separate due to prints contradicting
```